# prerequisites vs requirements vs qualifications

Tags: word-usage, difference

Can somebody please help me with an explaination about the difference between

- course prerequisites
- course entry requirements
- course qualifications

This is about a course which consists of different modules.
To start with the course the candidates must have some qualifications (or entry requirements?)
For every module the prerequisite is the candidate has succesfully ended the previous module.

Is this correct?
What is the difference between those three? (if there is any difference)

Answer (score 1):

In context they could all mean the same thing, or they could be different.

"Pre-requisites" are likely to be applied to individual courses at a college.  The pre-requisites might be other college courses, grades in tests, or general qualities that are needed.

> The prerequisites for the Calculus 2 course are **either** a passing grade in Calculus 1, **or** a high school mathematics certificate at an advanced level.  In addition, students require a willingness to work hard and must commit to finishing all the homework by the required deadline.

"Entry requirements" would be about something that you *enter*.  We talk about entering a college or university, but we say "you take Calculus" (we don't say "you enter calculus"). Thus it would make sense for "entry requirements" to be the grades that you need to enter the school, not particular pre-requisites for the courses at the school.

> The Entry requirements for Law at Oxford University are Three A-levels, two of which must be at A* grade and the third can be no lower than A grade.

"Course qualifications" is not a phrase I've heard used. Without other context, I'd assume it meant the qualification that you earned on completing the course.

> Course qualifications: The *Introduction to Computer Use* course will introduce the basics of word processor and spreadsheet design. This course is a pre-requisite for the *Computing in Business* course. In addition, all students who complete the course will also qualify for the ECDL certificate.